# Type annotation required when using `as_ref()` in `assert_eq!()`

Tags: rust, type-inference, traits

I'm using the new generic conversion traits in my code and experience reduced ergonomics. The code in question implements `AsRef<str> for [Ascii]` as you can see in the example.

Now I want to use `v.as_ref()` in `assert_eq!()` and expect that `v.as_ref()` returns a `&str` using the provided implementation because the second argument to `assert_eq!()` is of type `&str`.

There is no implementation of `AsRef<String> for [Ascii]` so in my opinion only one implementation of `PartialEq` comes into play: `PartialEq<str> for &str`.

The compiler doesn't follow my explanation and complains about required type annotations. How can I avoid the explicit annotation and why can't the compiler figure out the correct implementation of `AsRef<_>`?

Thanks

```
#![feature(convert)]

struct Ascii { chr: u8 }

impl AsRef<str> for [Ascii] {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { ::std::mem::transmute(self) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = [Ascii { chr: 65 }, Ascii { chr: 66 }];
    assert_eq!(v.as_ref(), "AB");
    // Workaround: explicit type annotation.
    //assert_eq!(AsRef::<str>::as_ref(&v[..]), "AB");
}
```

Playpen link: http://is.gd/ZcdqXZ

```
<anon>:15:18: 15:26 error: type annotations required:
    cannot resolve `[Ascii] : core::convert::AsRef<_>` [E0283]
<anon>:15     assert_eq!(v.as_ref(), "AB");
                       ^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [listed implementors of `AsRef`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#implementors) in the documentation in more detail and you find that there is another implementation that collides there: `impl<T> AsRef<[T]> for [T]`. So it can’t decide whether `v.as_ref()` should be of type `&str` or `&[Ascii]`.

Comment: Why doesn't the comparison to a known `&str` help guide type inference? Playing with some custom implementations of `AsRef` with multiple destination types, type inference seems to understand the "other type" and use it to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @Shepmaster: `assert_eq` does some slightly funky things that have a history of messing with inference a little, and changes in the past few days in particular have caused a little trouble. Hopefully this sort of case will be resolved in the near future, though I certainly can’t guarantee it.

Comment: But [it still fails with just a direct equality comparison](http://is.gd/O5WgsJ), which makes me think there is a second implementation that conflicts more directly somewhere. However, I also see that sometimes the [*order* of items](http://is.gd/UwBrBU) influences type inference, which seems like a bug, so I'll file that.

Comment: The issue is: [Order of operands to equality expression matters when inferring a AsRef implementation #23762](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23762)